# How to combine diagonal data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, aggregate

I am new to python, apologies if I do not explain well or provide partial solutions yet...

I have a dataframe as below: a key, some dates (distributed in rows), and many other columns (same key, same value)

| Key | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Column X | Column Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key 1 | 2022-01-01 |  |  | X11111111 | Y11111111 |
| Key 1 |  | 2022-01-02 |  | X11111111 | Y11111111 |
| Key 1 |  |  | 2022-01-03 | X11111111 | Y11111111 |
| Key 2 | 2022-12-01 |  |  | X22222222 | Y22222222 |
| Key 2 |  | 2022-12-02 |  | X22222222 | Y22222222 |
| Key 2 |  |  | 2022-12-03 | X22222222 | Y22222222 |

And I want to aggregate them like below, where the dates are aggregate, other columns keep the same

| Key | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Column X | Column Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Key 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | X11111111 | Y11111111 |
| Key 2 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-02 | 2022-12-03 | X22222222 | Y22222222 |

What would be the most efficient way of doing it? Thank you.

I have tried normal pivot and aggregation but did not work as I want ...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the empty cells are `NaN`, use [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
out = df.groupby('Key', as_index=False).first()
```

*NB. If the empty cells are empty strings, use `df.replace('', float('nan')).groupby('Key', as_index=False).first()`.*

Output:

```
     Key      Date 1      Date 2      Date 3   Column X   Column Y
0  Key 1  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-03  X11111111  Y11111111
1  Key 2  2022-12-01  2022-12-02  2022-12-03  X22222222  Y22222222
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
(df.groupby('Key', group_keys=True)
 .apply(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill())
 .drop_duplicates()
 .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
     Key      Date 1      Date 2      Date 3   Column X   Column Y
0  Key 1  2022-01-01  2022-01-02  2022-01-03  X11111111  Y11111111
1  Key 2  2022-12-01  2022-12-02  2022-12-03  X22222222  Y22222222
```